# Compare and swap

Tags: java, atomic

Is there any way to use CAS operations on more than 1 memory location in Java?

I am attempting to do three CAS operations one by one, but this has a problem of accessing 1st memory location (here old1) by a thread while next memory location (here old2) being compared by another thread. For instance,

```
if(CAS(old1,exp1,new1))

    if(CAS(old2,exp2,new2))

    if(CAS(old3,exp3,new3))
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
CAS(old1,old2,old3,exp1,exp2,exp3,new1,new2,new3)  ??
```

Comment: This isn't clear.  What behaviour are you aiming for here?

Comment: what is `CAS` in this case?  can you give some specifics?

Comment: I want to compare the three memory locations and only when they all match with their corresponding expected values,the CAS operation will write the new values... something like this,I guess.

Comment: CAS is an atomic operation. It is abbreviation for compareAndSwap().

Answer (score 3):

Put all three fields into one immutable object, a `Foo`.  Then, given an `AtomicReference<Foo> ref`, write:

```
Foo current = ref.get();
if (foo.val1() == exp1 && foo.val2() == exp2 && foo.val3() == exp3) {
  return ref.compareAndSet(current, new Foo(new1, new2, new3));
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want three `cas` operations together form an atomic operation, I think you need `synchronized` block/method.

You may also consider creating a wrapper class with three fields and doing CAS on reference:

```
public class ThreeValueHolder {
    private final int value0, value1, value2;

    public ThreeValueHolder(int value0, int value1, int value2) {
        this.value0 = value0;
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    //getters
}
```

And then use this class together with `AtomicReference`:

```
public volatile AtomicReference<ThreeValueHolder> ref = null;

...

ref.compareAndSet(current, new ThreeValueHolder(1, 2, 3));
```

Comment: I don't want to use locks or synchronized block/method for that matter. Anyway the wrapper class seems good alternative(instead of methods which block the threads).

Comment: I think I can also come up with some magic with `volatile` variable and memory `fences` that can provide visibility guarantees for the operation, but not atomicity. Anyway, glad to help as always.